# Contao DCA - How to set default value on multiple checkboxes

Tags: configuration, contao

Let's say we have a dca array like this:

```
$GLOBALS['TL_DCA']['tl_member']['fields']['publicFields'] = array
(
    ...
    'inputType'          => 'checkbox',
    'options'            => array('value1' => "label1", 'value2' => "label2");,  
    'eval'               => array('multiple'=>true, ...
);
```

Now we want to set the checkbox with value1 to checked by default.

I tried this but it does NOT work:

```
$GLOBALS['TL_DCA']['tl_member']['fields']['publicFields']['default'][0] = 'value1';
```

I found a description on https://de.contaowiki.org/Defaultwerte_vorbelegen. but it's for single value fields only not for multiple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array with your needed fieldnames for the declaration, e.g.:

```
$GLOBALS['TL_DCA']['tl_member']['fields']['publicFields']['default'] = array('firstname', 'lastname', 'dateOfBirth', 'street', 'postal', 'city', 'phone', 'mobile', 'email', 'website');
```

Comment: Thats it! Perfect! Just a little note: It is working only for new items, that means if you go to create a newone the fields are checked. If you have an 
already established item I guess you need a callback function. But in my case youre answer does exactly what I need. Thanks to Cliff!

Comment: Yes, thats right. Generally "defaults" are for the first creation. If you already have a lot of members entered, use "Edit multiple" -> "Overwrite" for a bulk update of all records.